# a href links within tabs not doing anything

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using following code for my bootstrap tabs in order to have the #name of the tab in the url, as I want to redirect to a specific tab once some post actions are done, which works fine.

However, ever since I started using the code, all the other  links stopped doing anything, it doesn't open the page or display an error, nothing at all.

Here's my code :

```
$(function() {
var gotoHashTab = function (customHash) {
    var hash = customHash || location.hash;
    var hashPieces = hash.split('?'),
    activeTab = $('[href=' + hashPieces[0] + ']');
    activeTab && activeTab.tab('show');
}

// onready go to the tab requested in the page hash
gotoHashTab();

// when the nav item is selected update the page hash
$('.nav a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash
    //location.hash = $(e.target).attr('href').substr(1);
    scrollTo(0,0);      
})

// when a link within a tab is clicked, go to the tab requested
$('.tab-pane a').click(function (event) {
    if (event.target.hash) {
        e.preventDefault();
        gotoHashTab(event.target.hash);
    }
})

$('.tab-pane a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault() 
})
```

});

I've noticed on some other questions, that `e.preventDefault()` may cause that, but when I comment those out nothing happens.

How to rewrite the code to keep functionality but make those normal links work again ?

Comment: activeTab = $('[href=' + hashPieces[0] + ']'); edit this to:

    activeTab = $('.tab-pane [href=' + hashPieces[0] + ']');

Answer (score 0):

It's looking at all the links with this:

```
  activeTab = $('[href=' + hashPieces[0] + ']');
```

Change to:

```
activeTab = $('.tab-pane [href=' + hashPieces[0] + ']');
```

And also try being more specific with the .nav, since .nav is default for all navs. So this:

```
$('.nav a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
```

Should change to:

```
 $('.tab-pane a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
```